# Someone want to help me with this javascript logic?

Tags: javascript, dom

Okay, so this is my problem. I'm kind of new to javascript so plz bear with me. I haven't found this issue somewhere else, and actually I think it's my logic that doesn't corespond to my willingness ;-)

I'm setting up a memory game with php and javascript. My problem is that when I first execute the clickCard-function it sets the variable firstClick to True with it's innerHTML-value and executes secondClick etc so long so fine, but if the guess is wrong only secondClick turns red. This because I believe that the first argument is static (and therfore saves the value of the color for firstClick), and I can't come up with a solution on how to solve this. I've tried diffrent things like creating conditions like if else(firstClick != 0 &&  firstClick != secondClick) {code} etc.

Anyone that can help me?

This is my code:

```
var firstClick = new Boolean();
firstClick.toString();

var secondClick = new Boolean();
secondClick.toString();
function clickCard(elem){               

    if(firstClick == 0){
        firstClick = document.getElementById(elem.id).innerHTML;
                    elem.style.backgroundColor = "green";   
        //alert(firstClick);
        }

    else{

        secondClick = document.getElementById(elem.id).innerHTML;
        //alert(secondClick);
        elem.style.backgroundColor = "green";


            if(firstClick == secondClick){
                alert(firstClick +" equals "+ secondClick);
                firstClick = new Boolean();
                secondClick = new Boolean();
            }

            else {
                alert(firstClick + " equals not " + secondClick);
                firstClick = new Boolean();
                secondClick = new Boolean();
                document.getElementById(elem.id).style.backgroundColor="red";
            }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your complete code on http://jsbin.com? It would be easier to debug for us who want to help.

Comment: can you post your html code part

Comment: need more info, html or a complete demo. by the way, use Boolean is always bad idea. just code `firstClick = false, secondClick = false`. I have to tell you `var a = new Boolean(), b = new Boolean();`, you'll find `a == b` is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems in your code. Take a look at my changes and try to understand them, and it should work:

1. initialize booleans with `var bool = true/false;`
2. don't mix the boolean with dom-elements
3. save your tiles in separate variables
4. actually set the color of the first tile to "red"

code:

```
var firstClick = true;
var piece1;
var piece2;

function clickCard(elem){               

    if(firstClick){
        piece1 = document.getElementById(elem.id);
        piece1.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        firstClick = false;  
    } else {

        piece2 = document.getElementById(elem.id);
        piece2.style.backgroundColor = "green";

        if(piece1.innerHTML == piece2.innerHTML){
            alert(firstClick +" equals "+ secondClick);
        } else {
            alert(firstClick + " equals not " + secondClick);
            piece1.style.backgroundColor="red";
            piece2.style.backgroundColor="red";
        }   
        firstClick = true;
    }
}
```

Now the advanced practice would be to put this into a closure to protect your "internal" values firstClick and piece1/2, but that's another story;)

Comment: thank you, I will try to gain knowledge trhough your code. :-)

Comment: you are welcome, let me know if this made it work or if you need further assistance.

Comment: it works if I'm adding if(firstClick){
        piece1 = document.getElementById(elem.id);
        piece1.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        firstClick = false;

and later piece1 = "", piece2 = "", where I set firstClick=true, the problem now is that the second click executes so fast that you never see it green. -_-

Comment: true, I forgot to set firstClick to false. However clearing the pieces should not be necessary. You could set a [Timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) to give some time before the cards are revealed.

Answer (score 1):

You are never actually telling the first element to change to red. You need to save the first clicked element in a variable, and set it at the same time as you set the second one.

Just a note, you should probably rethink your logic. For a start, you should have the game code in a closure, and generate the board there to make it inaccessible to outside access so people can't cheat by just looking at the source. Then when a card is clicked on, change its content to show what the card's value is, then blank it out again when you want to turn the card back over.

Comment: Aha, thank you sir! Yea, I've had the same thought I know it's a pretty bad idea to generate the game with php because as you said it makes it easy to cheat by just viewing source-code. But this is actually for a lab and the main thing is that it works. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a `innerHTML` value to a variable of type `Boolean`. 
its not all clear from this code.
Boolean object represents two values: "true" or "false". Also `firstclick.toString()` return the string value of your variable `firstclick` and does nothing else.

Check this whether this is what you intended.

```
var Clicked = true;
var First, Second;

function clickCard(elem){               

    if(Clicked){
        First = document.getElementById(elem.id);
        elem.style.backgroundColor = "green";   
        Clicked = false;
    } else {

        Second = document.getElementById(elem.id);
        elem.style.backgroundColor = "green";

        if(First.innerHTML == Second.innerHTML){
            alert(First.innerHTML +" equals "+ Second.innerHTML);
        } else {
            alert(First.innerHTML  + " equals not " + Second.innerHTML );
            First.style.backgroundColor="red";
            Second.style.backgroundColor="red";
        }   
        First = "";Second="";
        Clicked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: That code executes in the same way as mine, it never changes first to red. =/

Comment: hmm, no it's still not working because everything turns red even if it's a match. =/